# Visual studio 2019 create a project inside a src

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In the visual studio, I wanted to add a project inside the `src` folder.

For that, inside a solution explorer in visual studio, I created a folder called `src`.

[image]

After that, I created a new `ASP.NET Core Web API` project from, *File-> New Project* inside the 'Lazeez.Services.Restaurant\src' folder.

[image]

The project is created inside the `src` folder in the disk, but in visual studio, it is not seen under the src folder.

[image]

Comment: That's how VS works. That's not a problem. What you see in Solution Explorer isn't a folder structure, it's the projects inside a solution.

Comment: so how to add the project inside src in vs and in disk too?

Comment: I repeat, this isn't a folder structure. As in not related with the actual project placement at all. What you see is the projects added to the solution's `.sln` file. You could add projects from all over the disk and they'd still appear as a flat list of projects. You can create solution "folders" and put projects there but these aren't actual disk folders, they're simply a way to group projects. They only appear in the solution's `.sln` file. If you tried to create a new project inside an `src` solution folder it wouldn't be created inside an `src` disk folder by default.

Comment: Instead of creating or opening a Solution, you can use `Open Local Folder` in Visual Studio's initial page.

Comment: I understood how the vs works but I wanted to structure the project in the solution explorer exactly how it will be inside the disk. How to do it?

Comment: @AakashBashyal The solution explorer is a *logical* arrangement of files in your project. It need not bear any relationship to the folder / file structure on your disk.

Comment: There's no automated way. You'll have to create a solution folder and add the projects manually. Every time a new project is added you'll have to make sure it's placed in the correct solution folder. That's an annoying but cheap operation, since the only thing that changes is some lines in `.sln`